# Is it true that functions written in C cannot have **kwargs arguments?

Tags: python, c, split, cpython

Is there a reason why we need to use:

```
"test of split".split(" ")
```

and we can't use:

```
"test of split".split(sep=" ")
```

Of course split is implemented this way (in C). But does it really mean we cannot handle `**kwargs` for functions written in C?

Comment: "need to use".... what do you mean? Both work just fine.

Comment: @CoryKramer `TypeError: split() takes no keyword arguments` in 2.x

Comment: Right both versions work on 3.x, but just first version works on 2.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python functions implemented in C *can* be written to take keyword arguments - for example, `sorted(whatever, key=whatever)` - but many of them don't, mostly for historical reasons.

Note that on Python 3, you can now pass `sep` to `str.split` by keyword.